# QWidget's background applied to all its QWidget children

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets, qt5.6

I chose to use Qt to manage the GUI of a project I am working on.

After finding how to apply a picture at the bottom of my `QWidget`, I noticed that it has an impact on all the components that are added to it.

Whatever the style applied through the `setStyleSheet` method or even with a `QPixmap`, the background of these elements is always the image defined for the `QWidget` container.

**How can I avoid this behavior ?**

Here is my code :

```
MainMenu::MainMenu(QWidget* Parent, const QPoint& Position, const QSize& Size) : QWidget(Parent) {

    QString qwidgetStyle = "QWidget {background-image: url(background.jpg); border: 5px solid rgba(3, 5, 28, 1);}";
    QString buttonStyle = "color: rgba(73, 123, 176, 1); font-size:30px; background-color: rgba(73, 123, 176, 1);";

    move(Position);
    resize(Size);   
    setStyleSheet(qwidgetStyle);

    // Menu title
    QLabel *title = new QLabel(this);
    title->setText("Menu");
    title->setStyleSheet(buttonStyle);
    title->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);

    // Menu buttons
    // Play
    buttonPlay = new QPushButton("Play");
    (*buttonPlay).setEnabled(true);
    (*buttonPlay).setStyleSheet(buttonStyle);
    connect(buttonPlay, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(handleButton()));
    // Option
    buttonOptions = new QPushButton("Options", this);
    (*buttonOptions).setEnabled(true);
    (*buttonOptions).setGeometry(250, 175, 100, 50);
    (*buttonOptions).setStyleSheet(buttonStyle);
    connect(buttonOptions, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(handleButton()));
    // Quit
    buttonQuit = new QPushButton("Quit", this);
    (*buttonQuit).setEnabled(true);
    (*buttonQuit).setGeometry(250, 275, 100, 50);
    (*buttonQuit).setStyleSheet(buttonStyle);
    connect(buttonQuit, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(handleButton()));

    // Layout
    QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout;
    layout->setMargin(50);
    layout->addWidget(title, 0, 0, 1, 5);
    layout->addWidget(buttonPlay, 3, 1, 2, 3);
    layout->addWidget(buttonOptions, 4, 1, 2, 3);
    layout->addWidget(buttonQuit, 5, 1, 2, 3);
    setLayout(layout);

    show();
}
```

Comment: Does [this](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/14099-How-to-stop-child-widgets-from-inheriting-parent-s-StyleSheet-and-use-system-default) help? It seems to suggest using the name of the widget in the stylesheet and using the `setObjectName` method.

Comment: Would you care to write an answer @PaulRooney? This is the solution actually

Comment: @AlexisP. Please answer if you want. I don't really have the time to do a proper answer at the moment.

Comment: I hope this answer will meet your expectation as a commentator :p

Comment: Just for better reading i suggest you a constant coding style. Once you use `title->setText("Menu");` and sometimes `(*buttonPlay).setEnabled(true);` It's easier to read if you just use `buttonPlay->setEnabled(true);` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior you encountered is perfectly normal, because of the following lines :

```
QString qwidgetStyle = "QWidget {background-image: url(background.jpg); border: 5px solid rgba(3, 5, 28, 1);}";
...
setStyleSheet(qwidgetStyle);
```

Here, you just told Qt to apply `qwidgetstyle` to **every QWidget of your application**, with the keyword `QWidget`. That's why in Qt, you better set a name to your object if you want to apply a style to this particular object.

In your code, `QLabel` and `QPushButton` both inherit from `QWidget`, so they will have the style you defined for a `QWidget`, **unless you name them or you specify the style for each one**.

If you want to set style sheet for your `MainMenu` which inherits directly from `QWidget` (which is what you are doing in the first place), you have to set a name, and then apply the style :

```
setObjectName("MainMenu");
QString qwidgetStyle = "QWidget#MainMenu {background-image: url(background.jpg); border: 5px solid rgba(3, 5, 28, 1);}";
setStyleSheet(qwidgetStyle);  // here, only your MainMenu will have the style "qwidgetstyle"
```

Notice that you can, for example, set the same style sheet for every `QWidget`, and only add a particular color for your `MainMenu` :

```css
// this is in a CSS, but you can apply it directly from the MainMenu constructor of course
QWidget, QWidget#MainMenu {
    background-image: url(background.jpg); 
    border: 5px solid rgba(3, 5, 28, 1);
} // aplied to all QWidget

QWidget#MainMenu { 
    color : #9b9b9b; // a nice grey, only applied to MainMenu
}
```

Again, be specific when using style sheets or you will end up having strange colors/alignments everywhere in your application.